# Hotplugged condenser mic into scarlett 2i2, no more input?

Tags: daw

I was testing out some mics and I left the phantom power on and unplugged a condenser mic. I plugged in another mic and scarlett 2i2 isn't receiving anymore input (the indicators don't light up when talking into mics), the mics are confirmed to be working.

Did I fry the scarlett? Does hotplugging (I assume this means leaving phantom power on) fry things like these?

When I plug the scarlett into USB, the indicators blink 3 times in red, and computer recognizes it, but it doesn't receive/send signal from microphones.

Thanks.

Comment: have you contacted Focusrite/scarlett support/forums?

Comment: Check out this post here: https://m.reddit.com/r/audioengineering/comments/2bdx2u/focusrite_scarlett_2i2_not_picking_up_any_signal/ I own a Focusrite 2i2 myself and have plugged in/out cables with the phantom power on before and have had no issues personally. What type of cables are you using?

Comment: Yep, fried the circuits by hot plugging. Based on peoples' experiences, they're just badly built. Or luck of the draw. Thank you. Got another one, this time a PreSonus and works fine. Less noise/hiss too.